# Few metrics not working in Google Analytics Measurement Protocol

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am trying to track user visit server-side using this PHP snippet.

```
        $url = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/') + 1) . $alias);
        preg_match('~^[A-z]*~', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : '', $languages);
        $post = [
                'v' => 1,
                'uip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'tid' => GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE,
                'cid' => hash('sha256', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
                't' => 'pageview',
                'dl' => $url,
                'ua' => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '',
                'dr' => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '',
                'ul' => $languages[0],
            ];

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "User-Agent" => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '',
                "Referer" => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '',
                "Accept-Language" => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : '',
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

It seems to work partially.

What I can track:

- URL of page visits.
- Location of User
- Browser

What I can't track:

- Language of User (always "no set")
- Acquisition (everyone is "direct")

Tracking "Acquisition" is most important for me right now. How do I fix the code to track both these or at least Acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound strange but converting POST data to GET data seemed to do the job finally.

```
    if (!empty(GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE)) {
        $url = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/') + 1) . $alias);
        preg_match('~^[A-z]*~', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : '', $languages);
        $post = [
            'v' => 1,
            'uip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'tid' => GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE,
            'cid' => hash('sha256', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
            't' => 'pageview',
            'dl' => $url,
            'ua' => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '',
            'dr' => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '',
            'ul' => $languages[0],
        ];
        $headers = [
            "User-Agent" => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '',
            "Referer" => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '',
            "Accept-Language" => isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : '',
        ];
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?" . http_build_query($post),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        //var_dump($response, $post, "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?" . http_build_query($post),$headers);die;
    }
```